# Forces (Using Lagrange multipliers) of a fixed bicycle wheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

I'm having doubts about my Lagrangian when I release my constraints:

[image: image of the problem]

I'm using Euler angles and using a system which is referenced to the wheel. It's quite straightforward to get the Lagrange equations of motion if I don't free constraints. But if I do, I have some problems getting the force that makes the Z axis and the Bar united. Also, I want to get the Normal force. The disk rolls without slipping. Until now, I know that the constraints related to the Normal force is the Euler angle $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (the angle between the bar and the Z axis) and the constraint related to making the z axis and the bar is $z=constant$

My Lagrangian, which I have my doubts about, is

$$\begin{align}
L&=T_{old}+T_{new}+V_{new}\\
&=(\frac{1}{4}m(\frac{1}{2}r^2+3R^2)\dot{\zeta}^2)+(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2+\frac{1}{2}m\dot{z}^2)-(mgz)
\end{align}$$

where  $\zeta=\varphi+\frac{\pi}{2}$,$r$ is the radius of the disk and $R$ is the length of the bar.

Comment: You say the disk rolls without slipping, but you have a degree of freedom with your angle relative to z (suggesting that there is vertical motion). These things seem to be contradictory. Also - I did some editing for clarity: please make sure I did not alter your meaning.

Comment: The disk rolls without slipping, and its fixed to z=constant. If i want to use lagrange multipliers i need to set freet z. When i set free z, my potential energy is no longer a constant, but  m.g.z. Also my kinectic energy has z dot

Comment: Anyway, ignore my Lagrangian if you want. You can write the problem from the beginning if it is better for you.